# image not displaying in html string for addControl() from leaflet in R

Tags: html, r, leaflet, legend

I have the following code

```
myicon <- makeIcon( iconUrl = "myicon.ico" )
html_legend <- "<img src='myicon.ico'>hey<br/>"
map_leaflet <- leaflet() %>%
  addTiles() %>%
  addMarkers(50, 50, icon = myicon, popup = paste("geo")) %>%
  addControl(html = html_legend, position = "bottomright")
```

The map is correct, the icon on the map is good, and the popup as well.

In `addControl()` I want to display the icon as a legend. It displays the "question mark error icon" and not the actual image. On the other hand the word "hey" do appear.

Thank you in advance for your help. I do not understand what is missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question mark error icon means that it cannot find your image.

This is normal since during creation Leaflet is not running on a webserver. When you place your generated HTML-file on a webserver and the image icon in the appropriate place it will work.

I did this myself. Same error icon and worked like a charm when I placed it on the webserver. A [page that uses the same trick](http://abits-it.eu/nl/demos/gekapte-bomen-Utrecht.html).

Comment: Indeed, I was going to edit my question for I saw that the file.html generated did work in a webserver.
Thank you for confirming this and explaining at the same time.